# Explain CUDA out of memory in Pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, out-of-memory

Can anybody help me to explain the meaning of this common problem in Pytorch?

Model: EfficientDet-D4

GPU: RTX 2080Ti

Batch size: 2

```
CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 14.00 MiB (GPU 0; 11.00 GiB total capacity; 8.32 GiB already allocated; 2.59 MiB free; 8.37 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

Anyway, I think the model and GPU are not important here and I know the solution should be reduced batch size, try to turn off the gradient while validating, etc. But I just want to know what is the meaning of `8.32 GiB` while I have `11 GiB` but can not allocate `14.00 MiB` more?

Addition: I try to watch `nvidia-smi` while training with batch size = 1, it took `9.5 GiB` in my GPU.

Comment: Can you check the processes which are utilizing your GPU memory? Is there any previous ghost process already occupying the memory in the GPU device?

Comment: I restart the kernel, kill all processes after each time I try, so I am sure that there is nothing in there (even try to restart my computer)

Comment: You can see the GPU usage with `nvidia-smi`

Comment: @Tomer, I know that, but it just raised up to 10GiB then released all after the bug appeared, I will edit the question

Comment: try `torch.cuda.empty_cache()` and tell us how it goes.

Comment: @Rika It still returned the same result, and please don't misunderstand me, I don't want the solution to fix that bug, I want to know the meaning of those number in the error report.

Comment: Are you using colab or some environment like jupyter? if thats so, pytorch doesnt free the memory, unless you restart your runtime. it keeps the  memory in a pool so that next allocations can be done much faster.

Comment: I use my personal computer, and I think `11GiB` is enough to handle 1 image batch size is correct, because if I set batch size = 1, it runs normally and the `nvidia-smi` shows `9.5GiB`

Comment: How do you run your scripts? did you previously run with larger batchsizes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223676/discussion-between-toby-and-rika).

Comment: torch.cuda.empty_cache() doesn't help. I'm facing similar issue and can't figure out any solution?

Comment: @Raymond `toch.cuda.empty_cache()` helps to remove the redundant tensors from cuda, it doesn't help in case you want to fit a bigger model into your GPU memory.

Comment: I finally figured it out, the script has to be tweaked to optimise the RAM usage. empty_cashe() was not a solution for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the answer from @ptrblck in the Pytorch community. In there, I described my question in more detail than this question.

Please check the answer in [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/misunderstanding-cuda-out-of-memory/100727/2) .